# How to kill program in focus using a custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome

I'm hoping to write a custom keyboard shortcut that will kill whatever program is in focus. I'm basically trying to copy cmd+Q from apple. I'm running ubuntu 17.10 so this is with the new gnome desktop environment. Any suggestions would help.

Thank you

Comment: `Alt + F4` works with most GUI programs.

Comment: xkill command displays cross instead of cursor, If you click with left button, it kills current window,  if you click with right button, the command will stop. But this KILLS the window, so there can be data loss especially with libreoffice, so use this only if app freezes and doesn't respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for Cmd-Q functionality, that's akin to Alt-F4 which sends the window close event. Other programs have their own shortcuts to activate a full 'quit' event. (e.x. Ctrl-Shift-Q in Chrome)

If you want to *kill* the current program in focus, we can set that up using a keyboard shortcut.

There's a similar question on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/757160/kill-the-currently-active-window-with-a-keyboard-shortcut

From Kamil's answer: `xdotool getwindowfocus windowkill` will kill the current active window.

You can learn about setting these shortcuts in the official Ubuntu docs: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html